# Which subspaces are isometric to $\ell_p^n(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $m > n$, and suppose $V$ is an $n$-dimensional subspace of $\ell_p^m(\mathbb{R})$. I would like to know when $V$ is isometric to $\ell_p^n(\mathbb{R})$.

For $p = 2$, it is clear that $V$ is always isometric to $\ell_p^n(\mathbb{R})$, and an isometry is any orthogonal matrix sending a basis of $V$ to the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does an isometry exist for $p \not = 2$?